# E3 license clean up in Disabled user AD

Tags: powershell, automation, azure-active-directory

I need some help with a script :)

This script look in our AD for disabled accounts.
Import to CSV then "compare through 0365 and check if the user have E3 license.

So what I would need help with is  maybe if else or try catch statements.
So if user are disabled in AD and have a E3 license export to CSV file.

When I ran script I get user not found red text is the maybe a way to handle all error text?
Thanks in advance

```
$DisabledAccounts = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | 
                        Select userprincipalname | 
                        Export-csv "C:\\Temp\\disabledADUser.csv"   
$user = Import-Csv "C:\\Temp\\disabledADUser"  
$user | ForEach-Object {  
   $0365User= Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $\_.UserPrincipalName | 
                  Where-Object {($\_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "SPE\_E3"} | 
                  Select userprincipalnameione -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
   if ($0365User) {  
      Write-Host " " -ForegroundColor "red"  
   }else {  
      Write-Host ""  -ForegroundColor "green"  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid filtering with curly brackets : `-Filter { Enabled -eq $false }`, but use instead double quotes `-Filter "Enabled -eq $false"`

However, since you only need `UserPrincipalName` attributes, I would prefer `Search-ADAccount` cmdlet.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | ForEach-Object `
       -Begin { $o365Users = @() } `
       -Process { $o365Users += Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName | 
              Where-Object {($_.Licenses).AccountSkuId -match "SPE_E3"} | 
              Select UserPrincipalName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } `
       -End { $o365Users } | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\DisabledADUserWithLicenseAttached.csv"
```

the `-Begin` parameter for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet is called at start only once to create an array which is populate in the `-Process` block, when all users have been verified, the `-End` block outputs the array to be converted into a csv.

For your information MSOnline PowerShell Module will be removed at the end of the year. You should consider using the Microsoft.Graph module instead ([Here some informations about license management with it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/assign-licenses-to-user-accounts-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide)). You can also use PnP.PowerShell which is a very powerfull non-Microsoft and open source module but referenced by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets).

Comment: Thank you @CFou so much for the PS-hell help, it worked like a charm :). Ok I will check out the Microsoft.Graph module and pNp.PS open source *I have checked it out retirement date:March 31, 2023, so if I would convert the script to Microsoft Graphhow would the script it look like. Would it  look the same but just change to ex.Get-MgUser (get-MsolUser)

Comment: It should, but weirdly not, at least not always. Consider `Get-MgUserLicenseDetail` cmdlet